# How to get the value of last row in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a table that contains some data. I know that I can access of my first row like this,

```
  Object nameOfFile = Main_Menu.jTable3.getValueAt(0, 0);
  String nameOfFileToString = nameOfFile.toString();
```

My table is dynamic. Sometimes my row of the table is 100, sometimes is 200. How can I get the last row of my table even my table is dynamically change.

P.S : my table is connected with a jfreechart, so I need this for my update Y axis in jfreechart like this

```
Object nameOfFile = Main_Menu.jTable3.getValueAt(0, 0);
    String nameOfFileToString = nameOfFile.toString();



    // create the chart...
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
            "Persentastion Of Similarity", // chart title
            "", // domain axis label
            nameOfFileToString, // range axis label
            dataset, // data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
            true, // include legend
            true, // tooltips
            false // urls
    );
```

for the help, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use `JTable.getModel().getRowCount()` to get the number of rows; the rest is straightforward:

```
Object nameOfFile = Main_Menu.jTable3.getValueAt(jTable3.getModel().getRowCount()-1, 0);
// go on with your code
```

Comment: +1, for the concept, but you should be using `JTable.getRow()` instead of the row count from the model. These values may not be the same if the table is filtered. In general, you should always use either the table methods (getValueAt(), getRowCount()) or the TableModel methods of the same name. Don't mix and match. Yes, in this case it probably doesn't make a difference, but you should understand the difference between each of the methods.

Comment: @camickr I agree; the code was added by hd1, though ;). If using row sorters, you need to use `JTable.getRowSorter()` to find the correct model row index. I was unaware of `JTable.getRowCount()`; it probably delegates to `TableModel` anyways but I'm too lazy to look it up right now.

Comment: `If using row sorters, you need to use JTable.getRowSorter() to find the correct model row index` you would use the "JTable.convertRowIndexToModel()" method, however in this case it isn't need if you get the data directly from the table since the table invokes this method internally. `it probably delegates to TableModel` no, because if you filter the table then the view shows fewer rows than the model contains.

Comment: @camickr Ah okay ^^ Well I didn't work with filtering tbh. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all of you. 
This code is rock

```
Object nameOfFile = Main_Menu.jTable3.getValueAt(jTable3.getModel().getRowCount()-1, 0);
```

Now, my application is looking fine. I haven't try getrowSorter but soon I will try.
Once again, thanks...